# How to split my dataframe into X and Y based on conditon?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, from a column (say 'XY') of numeric data, I desire to come up with 2 more columns, 'X' and 'Y' where 'X' is a column of lists of every 20 elements from 'XY' and 'Y' is every 21st element of 'XY'. Maybe by illustration...

[image: illustrative image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sample illustrative image , this code will do what you need for this task , just few notes :

- This is smaller sub-problem with size 2 instead of 20 , to make it of size 20 , just change the `OFFSET` value to 20 or as desired and use your own df instead of this sample one.
- Here take care for your problem the last 19 ( OFFSET-1 ) elements of X will have elements less than 20 , and decays 20,19,18..etc. , also you can do it however you want ex : fill the rest size with NULL/None values.
- For the last 20 ( OFFSET ) elements of y , there will not be a valid value to set , i choose here to set NULL/None ( NaN in dataframe ) , you can change it.

and finally here is the code ,

```
import pandas as pd 

# sample dataframe to test 
df = pd.DataFrame([10,20,30,40,50,60],columns=["xy"])

x = []
y = []
OFFSET = 2
ln = len(df['xy'])

for i in range(ln):

    x_value = None 
    y_value = None 

    # x values
    x_value = df['xy'][i:min(i+OFFSET,ln)]
    x_value = list(x_value)

    # y values 
    if i+OFFSET < ln : 
        y_value = df['xy'][i+OFFSET]
    
    x.append(x_value)
    y.append(y_value) 

df['x'] = x
df['y'] = y
print(df)
```